# Matplotlib skips data -

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar chart using matplotlib. My issue is I have some "0" values in the list and matplotlib eats some of these values, how do I make sure it always plots all the values.

Here is the code:

```
counter_trim = counter[6:(len(counter)-6)]
pos = np.arange(len(Test_names[6:]))

width =.65

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_ylabel('Number of failures')
ax.set_title('Distribution of ABT failures')
ax.set_xticks(pos + (width/2))

xtickNames= ax.set_xticklabels(Test_names[6:])

plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=90, fontsize=10)
plt.bar(pos, counter_trim, width, color='b')

plt.tight_layout()
print 'Distribution plot can be found here:' +image_filepath
plt.savefig(image_filepath)
```

To make things more clear,
here are the values of pos : [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]

and values of counter_trim: [0, 0, 0, 1, 17, 6, 0, 14, 32, 11, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0]

The code above skips first 3 and last 2 zeros, but rest everything is same!

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? And can you clean up your example code so it can just run (ie, put your example data in the snipit, get rid of the xlabel details)?  This smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out something like this:

```
plt.xlim(0, len(counter_trim))
```

as he is drawing no actual bar I guess the plot command omits these entries. I could not try it with your labels on x as they are not with the text but this worked with a standard axis.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. maybe mark it as the solution then (;